# Single consumer of events

Tags: masstransit

all new to Masstransit and are currently evaluating it for a larger project and
wondering if anyone could help get a better understanding of the following challenges:

**"Single consumer of events in a loadbalanced environment"**
In production our services will be runinng multiple instances for scalability and failvover and be
part of a larger ecosystem of microservices. The overall architecture is based on Microsofts eshoponcontainers
reference implementation where different microservices are communicating with each other via "integrationevents".
When publishing a IntegrationEvent to other services which I assume should be done as described in Masstransit Producers / Publish
, https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish, how can I assure that only ONE instance in a specific microservice are processing
the event but of course that the event reaches ALL microsystem that depends on the event? When we have done similar solutions based on Azure Functions
this requirement has been solved by using the "Singelton" attribute (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute).

**Azure Service Bus**
Reading the documentation my impression is that Masstransit is very RabbitMQ centric.
Since we will be on the Azure Service bus when moving to production is there any limitations or features
not available on that "transport"?

Regards Niclas

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it's a normal [publish-subscribe](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html) with competing consumers. It works like this out of the box, there's nothing that needs to be done to achieve this.

> When running multiple instances of the same service
>
> - Use the same queue name for each instance
> - Messages from the queue will be load balanced across all instances (the competing consumer pattern)

It's from the RMQ Guidances, but it's like this for all transports.

Concerning the Azure Service Bus transport, it works as expected and has a lot of production users. It's properly [documented](http://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/azure-sb.html) as well.

I'd say for both of your questions the answer is "**it just works**".

Comment: Hi Alexey and thanks for taking time to answear my question!
Im in doubt if have explained my requirements good enough when i read your reply. 
IntegrationEvents should reach ALL microsystems but only one instance in each of these microsystems should process the event / message (IntegrationEvent). I read your reply as solution based on queues (competing) instead of a topic based approach where the model is one message to many subscribers. Publishing one message to many isnt the real problem, it's how to assure that the event is only processed by one instance in each microsystem.

Comment: The topic vs queue terminology is transport-specific. As I said, as soon as multiple instances of the same service are running, only one will get a message. I am not sure where the doubt comes from. It's quite trial to quickly prototype and see it for yourself.

Comment: You are right, I will try it and get my hands dirty! Thanks for your help Alexey!